# Как сделать отображение логотипа при запуске webview ios

Tags: ios, webview

Задача такая, при запуске webview приложения на iOS отображать логотип на белом фоне 3секунды.

Answer (score 0):

Не советуется при старте приложения задерживать отображение LaunchScreen. Если хотите - пропишите в `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    sleep(3)
    return true
}
```

Но это совсем плохой вариант.

Лучше сделать вариант, что при запуске накладывается `UIView` c необходимыми элементами поверх `WebView`, которая в это время начинает загрузку нужной страницы. По окончании загрузки страницы (или по таймеру) эта `UIView` скрывается/убирается.